# Android onPause issue

Tags: android

I have a search function in my app, and I have the searching activity called SearchPage2.java, and also another activity (SearchTaDa.java) that shows more info when a list Item is clicked. I've discovered that I can't call `finish()` in `onPause()` in SearchPage2.java because I want the ListView to still be visible when you press my software back button (or the hardware Back Button) from SearchTaDa.java. But because I'm not calling `finish()` in SearchPage2.java, when you press the hardware home button to exit the app, then restart the app, it goes right back to the SearchPage2 activity rather than restarting the app from the splash screen, the beginning of the app. So the SearchPage2 onPause looks like:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
}
```

and the More Info Activity, SearchTaDa.java onPause looks like:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    finish();
}
```

My question is what can I call in the SearchPage2 activity so that when you restart the app it starts fresh, and doesn't resume at the search page?

Comment: Pressing the home button is not supposed to exit the app. It just puts it into into the background. If the user wants to exit the app and restart it, that's what the back button (or back action bar item) is for.

Answer (score 0):

Set a global flag "destroyOnResume" and call finish [onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) if your flag is set.

More in detail:

Somewhere in your code you figure out if the SearchPage2Activity should be finished the next time it is called and adjust your flag, which is somewhere in the code e.g as a global member...

```
public static boolean destroySearchPage2OnResume = false;
```

or put it into your [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to persist this even when the App gets killed.

In SearchPage2.java you override the onResumeMethod, which gets called after onRestart() or onPause() when your App goes into the background. If your flag is set to true, you finish the SearchPage2 Activity right away.

```
@Override
protected void onResume () {
   super.onPause();
   if(destroySearchPage2OnResume){
   this.finish();
   }  
}
```

By the way, it would be cleaner to call your activitys with the [no-history-flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) instead of killing it onPause...

Comment: I understand the no-history-flag idea, but could you give me a code sample of destroyOnResume please? I don't understand what you mean by it.

Comment: ` protected void destroyOnResume() {
  SearchPage2.this.finish();
 }` is this correct? if so, it doesn't appear to do anything in my app.